# Spark 2.0 read csv number of partitions (PySpark)

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to port some code from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.0 using new stuffs from Spark 2.0. First, I want to use the csv reader from Spark 2.0. BTW, I'm using pyspark.

With the "old" `textFile` function, I'm able to set the minimum number of partitions. Ex:

```
file= sc.textFile('/home/xpto/text.csv', minPartitions=10)
header = file.first() #extract header
data = file.filter(lambda x:x !=header) #csv without header
...
```

Now, with Spark 2.0 I can read the csv directly:

```
df = spark.read.csv('/home/xpto/text.csv', header=True)
...
```

But I didn't find a way to set the `minPartitions`.

I need this to test the performance of my code.

Thx,
Fred

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no: you can't set a minimum bar using a mechanism similar to the minPartitions parameter if using a DataFrameReader.

`coalesce` may be used in this case to reduce the partitions count, and `repartition` may be used to increase the partition count. When you are using `coalesce`, downstream performance may be better if you force a shuffle by providing the shuffle parameter (especially in cases of skewed data): `coalesce(100,shuffle=True)`.  This triggers a **full** shuffle of data, which carries cost implications similar to `repartition`.

Note that the above operations generally do *not* keep the original order of the file read (excepting if running `coalesce` without the shuffle parameter), so if a portion of your code depends on the dataset's order, you should avoid a shuffle prior to that point.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.
The DataFrame (and RDD) has a method called "coalesce". Where the number of partitions can be set.

Ex:

```
>>> df = spark.read.csv('/home/xpto/text.csv', header=True).coalesce(2)
>>> df.rdd.getNumPartitions()
2
```

In my case, Spark splited my file in 153 partitions. I'm able to set the number of partitions to 10, but when I try to set to 300, it ignores and uses the 153 again (I don't know why).

REF:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce

Comment: as per documentation `coalesce()` can only be used to decrease the number of partitions. `coalesce()` will not increase the number of partitions. for that you must use `repartition()` and pay to cost of a data shuffle around spark workers.